# Empty question and answer view on specific question

Tags: bug, android-app

I saw on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865139/stackoverflow-doing-boxing-in-c) today, viewing it through the Android app, that the question body, and answers body is missing.

This is the first time I saw this problem.

[image: screenshot of problem]